# How can a socket.io room name be passed from the front end to the back end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I am currently making an application that is using React.js on the front end and Node.js on the back end. During development, I discovered that I needed to use sockets in order to reflect real time changes to all of the users in a particular room. To do this, I am using this code on my Node.js backend:

```
io.emit("name", {
           action: "action",
           data: data
       });
```

and then to receive the requests on my front end I am doing this:

```
import openSocket from "socket.io-client";
const socket = openSocket(url);
socket.on("name", (data) => {
      ... logic
});
```

While this code works, I am currently emitting information to all players that are connected to my socket. However, I only want to emit information to the players in a certain room. The part I dont understand is how to tell socket.io which users are in a certain room. I read the documentation and the concept of rooms seems to be only a server side thing, and to add a player to a room this code can be used:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.join('some room');
});
```

But the room name I want this particular connection to join is stored on my front end. Is there a way I can pass this data from the front end to the back end so that it can be used when 'connection' is made? If not, how do I get the roomID I need? Thanks!

Comment: You can use a normal API request to pass the array of valid rooms (assuming that's what you want to do), pass the data along with a socket callback--whatever suits your application needs best.

Comment: Hello! How do I pass data into the socket callback from the frond end? Because "connection" is executed when I do `const socket = openSocket(url);`

Comment: Check the [docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html#socket-on-eventName-callback)--you can register a callback with any `.on` message.

Comment: This is my first time making a full stack application so I am still kind of confused. I understand that I can pass in a callback when using .on but dont understand how that will solve my problem. Right now, my node.js application needs a roomID, which is stored on the front end. I need it when this happens: 
`io.on('connection', socket => { });`. And  `io.on("connection")` executes when I do `const socket = openSocket(url);` on my front end. How do I use a callback to assist the transfer of data between `const socket = openSocket(url);` and 
`io.on('connection', socket => { });`

Comment: The server can register a message handler like `socket.on("join room", roomId => socket.join(roomId))`. The client can then `socket.emit("join room", 42)` to say they want to join room 42. Client might need to request to get a list of valid rooms earlier, and server probably should validate that the room exists, etc, but this is the basic idea. Is this what you're looking for?